# Custom Drawables with android

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, drawable

I have searched EVERYWHERE for an answer to this.

I am trying to work out how to draw a custom shape made in xml to a bitmap or to a canvas.

This is my simple xml code for a rectangle.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#f0f000" />
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ff0000" />
   </shape>
```

Then here, I am trying to simply get the shape and put it on a bitmap, then draw that bitmap to the canvas?

```
    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shape);

    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, canvas.getHeight() /2, canvas.getWidth()/2, p);
```

If anyone can help I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *drawable*... try this:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);
drawable.setBounds(0,0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

NB: Obviously you can do the getDrawable() bit just once, rather than on every draw().